# form action inside foreach works only for the first value of php

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have created a form where every time, it would store a different id during foreach loop

```html
<?php
foreach ($res as $r) {
                        ?>
<form id="clearitem" action="clearitem.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="clearitem" value="<?php echo $r['cart_id'];?>">
<button type="Submit">&times;</button>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

and the retrieval of the data works perfectly, it shows me each and every id one after another, but when I click the button (in this case to clear the item) it only works for the first value i.e. if I click the button for the second or the third value, it deletes the first one only, not the one corresponding to the button.

please do help, why this is happening and the appropriate solution, if anyone can provide!

the clearitem.php

```html
 if(isset($_POST['clearitem'])){
            $clear=$_POST['clearitem'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE id=".$clear;

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record deleted successfully of id".$clear;
} else {
  echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
}
```

Comment: usually you put only the input in the loop, else you get as many forms as you have ids. Beside that the question is not complete clear as the sense of the whole code and idea is not clear.

Comment: @David hello, thank you for replying, that was my criteria, to create as many forms as per the iterations, but my question is for every iteration, I have different values (the cart_id) as you can see in the code, but the submit takes value of the first iteration only, even if I click the submit for second or third iterations!

Comment: All your forms have the same id, so the button event can't distinguish between the forms.

Comment: @Subhraneel. Your problem seems **NOT** reproducible.  See this [testing_link](http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO22May2022.php) (click to see the effect) . So there must be other code you have not posted which is causing problem(s)

Comment: @David but isn't the value different for each iteration <?php echo $r[cart_id] one? even though the name attribute is same, the value is being changed at every iterations and submit should take the correspondent value, it should not be the same for every iteration right? also the output is showing the different values!

Comment: @KenLee can you share the php code of that! Yes thats my criteria only!

Comment: @KenLee showed that I did mistake, so it might be related to more code, like he wrote already, or to the file clearitem.php.

Comment: @David updated the question with the clearitem.php

Comment: (a) You need one more `}` at the end of the clearitem.php (to close the `if` clause) (b) Please use parameterized prepared statement for the delete query

Comment: @KenLee yes, I accidentally forgot to copy that from the editor! but still the same error, but the output which you shared is my solution, can you post a reply with the php code! It would be really helpful!

Comment: @KenLee pardon but you have not used foreach and you didn't used php echo from that foreach as value, without the foreach and php echo, even I am able to work around with static value! I am trying to find a solution the code by dynamic value i.e. the one where I am retrieving the value from the database using foreach

Comment: Bro, Using `Foreach` or use `static forms` will not make any difference. Because the generated code is at the client side for submission to another php (clearitem.php)

Comment: @KenLee but it is making a difference! thats what my query! if possible, please do create a dummy table in sql and try to make the required action using foreach! Please! It would be really helpful! reply to your edit - this is why I didn't posted my clearitem.php, because I also know the value can be anything generated from the previous page, but the issue is happening on the form, where it is sending the first value only for foreach.

Comment: Please see my suggested answer (tested - 100% work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to solve this issue, and the solution is the "id" so when you are using foreach, for every iteration, it is re-creating the form with the different value of the input, of course!

But the problem is the id-field, even if the input value is different, but the id is same for every iteration and therefore, even if you click a different button i.e. the 2nd or 3rd, the POST request will consider the initial value as the actual value, i.e. the first iteration, just because the id was same!

It's similar to the concept of first-come-first-serve. Since the POST request getting the value of the first element correspondent to the id, therefore that will the final value of that specific id and no amount how many times you iterate, the value will not be updated if you use the same id.

The possible fix is to have a different id, with each different iteration and that was made possible with putting the foreach value in the id.

```html
<?php
foreach ($res as $r) {
                        ?>
  <form id="clearitem<?php echo $r['cart_id'];?>" action="clearitem.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="clearitem" value="<?php echo $r['cart_id'];?>">
    <button type="Submit">&times;</button>
  </form>
  <?php
}
?>
```

by this for every iteration, the value of the id will be different, like if cart_id are as:1, 2, 3 then the ids would be clearitem1, clearitem2, clearitem3. By this the POST request will be retrieving different values since the ids are different!

Answer (score 0):

The system should be able to correctly process the submitted data according to the data value `in each form` in such a "multi-form" environment.

Hence the code below should work (tested):

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","dbuser","dbpassword","dbname");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();

foreach ($res as $r) {
?>

<form id="clearitem" action="clearitem.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="clearitem" value="<?php echo $r['cart_id'];?>">
<button type="Submit">&times;</button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

The following is the `clearitem.php` code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["clearitem"])) {

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","dbuser","dbpassword","dbname");
$sql = "delete FROM cart where cart_id=?" ;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 

$id=$_POST["clearitem"]; 
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
}
?>

<script>
    alert("Done !");
    if ('referrer' in document) {
        window.location = document.referrer;
        /* OR */
        //location.replace(document.referrer);
    } else {
        window.history.back();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! But I took another approach, the issue was that for every iteration, a form was created and it was using the same id! So, I put the php index value in the id and viola it solved!